# Question on a construction of the Klein-Beltrami model

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

I was reading N. Hitchin's lecture notes [Chapter 4 The Klein programme](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/files/LectureNotes/Projective_geometry/Chapter_4_The_Klein_programme.pdf).
At the beginning of page 67, Hitchin wrote that

> We consider the subset $D\subset P^2(\mathbf{R})$ defined by
> $$ D = \{[a,b,c]\in P^2(\mathbf{R}): b^2-4ac<0\}. $$
> If $a+c=0$, then $b^2-4ac>0$ so $D$ lies in the complement of the line $a+c=0$ in $P^2(\mathbf{R})$ and we can regard $D$ as the interior of the circle $(b/(a+c))^2+((a-c)/(a+c))^2 = 1$ in $\mathbf{R}^2$. The group $PGL(2,\mathbf{R})$, and its subgroup $PSL(2,\mathbf{R})$, acts naturally on this space of quadrics.

Hitchin said that historically, $D$ is the Klein-Beltrami model.

**Question:** Could someone explain how the group $PSL(2,\mathbf{R})$ acts naturally on $D$? I am thinking that maybe Hitchin means that $PSL(2,\mathbf{R})$ preserves the interior of the unit circle in $\mathbf{R}^2$. But this is clearly not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed at the bottom of page 66, a point $[a,b,c]\in D$ can be thought of as the equation for a quadric $$ax_0^2+bx_0x_1+cx_1^2$$ in $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$.  The group $PGL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts on the set of such quadrics by acting on the variables $x_0$ and $x_1$: an element of $PGL(2,\mathbb{R})$ gives a linear substitution to make for $x_0$ and $x_1$ which transforms the quadric into a different quadric.  Or, in geometric terms, $PGL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{R})$ and maps the subscheme defined by one quadric to the subscheme defined by another quadric.

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed a natural way to obtain an action. Could you also look at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1503127/every-geometry-is-a-projective-geometry-so-is-hyperbolic-geometry-a-projectiv)? The answer by Thomas is quite interesting in that he mentioned the group $PSO(n,1)$, and I wonder whether his construction is the same as Hitchin's.

Comment: Oops, I realize that my answer is wrong--the action I describe is the action that is used for the Poincaré disk model not the Beltrami-Klein model.  I'll edit to correct it.

Comment: As for the connection to $PSO(n,1)$, I don't know off the top of my head, but presumably there is some isomorphism between $PSO(2,1)$ and $PGL(2,\mathbb{R})$ that makes the actions the same, since both groups are supposed to be the isometry group of the Beltrami-Klein model.